# Set a wait time for a statement in C#

Tags: c#, wait

I am using a webclient in C#.

```
  returnValue = webclient.uploadstring(url, Message)
```

It works fine if the connection and all the other credentials are fine. But if any mistake in either the credentials or the connection, it waits for the webclient for at least 5 minutes to respond. I just want to set say 30 seconds for the command to get executed and if i dont get response abort it. How do I do so? is there a way?

Comment: Yeah. THe next one not knowing how to use search ;) Definitely a duplicate - it is not "wait time", the term is - pretty much everywhere - TIMEOUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this code you are looking for?

```
webclient.Timeout = 500;
returnValue = webclient.uploadstring(url, Message);
```